# delete goods from table using mysql php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem where i cant delete a row in the table i have. When i select something and click on delete, nothing happends its just refresh the page and i can select again, but the row is still there. I use the code on this page: index.php?page=Delete

Below is my code:

```
        try{

        if($DBH == null)
        $DBH = new PDO($dsn, $dbuser, $dbpass);
    }
    catch (PDOException $e){
    echo '<b>PDOException: </b>',$e->getMessage();
    die();
    }


    $action = empty($_GET['']) ? "" : $_GET[''];

    if ($action == "")  # No action specified so show the home page 
    {
    try{
        $sql = "select id, name, price from goods";

        $STH = $DBH->query($sql);

        $STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);  

        echo "<form method='post' >";
        echo "<table border='1'>";

        echo "<tr><th>Name</th><th>Price</th><th>Select</th></tr>";
        while ($row = $STH->fetch()) 
        { 
            echo "<tr><td><br>{$row["name"]} {$row["price"]} </td>"; 
            echo "<td>";
            echo "<input type='radio' value='{$row["id"]}' name='id2edit'>"; 
            echo "</td></tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>"; 
        echo "<br>"; 
        echo "<input type='submit' value='Delete selected product'            name='button'>"; 
        echo "</form>";

        $DBH = null;
        }
        catch (PDOException $e){
        echo '<b>PDOException: </b>',$e->getMessage();
        die();
        }

        } 

        else if ($action == "action='index.php?page=Delete'") 
        { 

        $id2edit = empty($_POST["id2edit"]) ? "" : $_POST["id2edit"];
        if ($id2edit == "")
        {
        $m = "No goods selected! To return to the home "; 
        $m .= "screen click <a href='delcust.php'>here.</a>"; 
        show_message($m);
        }
        else
        {
        try{

            $STH = $DBH->prepare('delete from goods where id = :id');
            $STH->bindParam(':id', $id2edit);
            $STH->execute(); 
            $DBH = null;
           }
        catch (PDOException $e){
            echo '<b>PDOException: </b>',$e->getMessage();
            die();
         }
       } 
        }
```

I have come further now but still the value in teh table is not deleted: here is the code i have right now:

```
     try{
     # a DB Handler to manage the database connection
     if($DBH == null)
    $DBH = new PDO($dsn, $dbuser, $dbpass);
    }
    catch (PDOException $e){
    echo '<b>PDOException: </b>',$e->getMessage();
    die();
    }



    $action = empty($_GET['action']) ? "" : $_GET['action'];

    if($action == "Delete"){
    try{
    $sql = "select id, name, price from goods";

    $STH = $DBH->query($sql);

    $STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);  

    echo "<form method='post' action='delcust.php?action=delete_record'>";
    echo "<table border='1'>";

    echo "<tr><th>Name</th><th>Price</th><th>Select</th></tr>";
    while ($row = $STH->fetch()) 
    { 
    echo "<tr><td><br>{$row["name"]} </td> <td> {$row["price"]} </td>"; 
    echo "<td>";
    echo "<input type='radio' value='{$row["id"]}' name='id2edit'>"; 
    echo "</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>"; 
    echo "<br>"; 
    echo "<input type='submit' value='Delete selected product' name='button'>"; 
    echo "</form>";

    $DBH = null;
    }
    catch (PDOException $e){
    echo '<b>PDOException: </b>',$e->getMessage();
    die();
    }
    }
    else if ($action == "delete_record") 
    { 
        include("header.php");
        include("nav.php");
        include("aside.php");

     $id2edit = empty($_POST["id2edit"]) ? "" : $_POST["id2edit"];
    if ($id2edit == "")
    {
    $m = "No goods selected so far! Please select"; 
    echo("$m");
    }
    else {
    try{

    $STH = $DBH->prepare('delete from goods where id = :id');
    $STH->bindParam(':id', $id2edit);
    $STH->execute(); 
    echo "Goods with ID $id2edit deleted. :id To return to the home "; 
    echo "screen click <a href='index.php'>here.</a>";  
    $DBH = null;
   }

    catch (PDOException $e){
    echo '<b>PDOException: </b>',$e->getMessage();
    die();
    }
    include("footer.php");
    } 
    }
    ?>
```

Problem solved:

```
     $sql = "delete from goods where id = :id";
     $STH = $DBH->prepare($sql);
```

now it works do delete values.

Comment: Table is  [reserved keyword](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/keywords.html) in mysql it must be in backtick

Comment: ah i have another name for it, jsut changed it to print out here :)

Comment: `echo "<tr><td><br>{$row["name"]} {$row["price"]} </td>"; ` should be `echo "<tr><td><br>{$row['name']} {$row['price']} </td>"; `

Comment: @AshishChoudhary isn't that the same code ?

Comment: then post your actual code!!

Comment: It is exactly like that only table is = goods, i can change it

Comment: @lamnoobatSQL. There is a difference in the code. I have replaced double quotes `"` with single quotes `'`

Comment: @AshishChoudhary ah saw it now, i changed it but it doesnt work :/

Comment: Are you sure its going inside Delete part? As I can see its always going inside `if ($action == "")`. Try `echo $id2edit; exit;` under `$id2edit = empty($_POST["id2edit"]) ? "" : $_POST["id2edit"];` And check if its really coming there.

Comment: @AshishChoudhary I got no echo to the screen, uhm.. why is it not going into the delete part?

Comment: `empty($_GET[''])` is always true as `$_GET['']`  is always undefined., therefore `$action` is always empty and it never goes inside delete part.
let me post the solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

`if ($action == "")`  is always true as `$_GET['']` is always undefined(and return NULL) and `empty($_GET[''])` is always true.

Try below code:

```
try {

    if ($DBH == null)
        $DBH = new PDO($dsn, $dbuser, $dbpass);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo '<b>PDOException: </b>', $e->getMessage();
    die();
}


$action = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : '' ; // MODIFIED

if ($action == "Delete") { // MODIFIED

    $id2edit = empty($_POST["id2edit"]) ? "" : $_POST["id2edit"];
    if ($id2edit == "") {
        $m = "No goods selected! To return to the home ";
        $m .= "screen click <a href='delcust.php'>here.</a>";
        show_message($m);
    } else {
        try {

            $STH = $DBH->prepare('delete from goods where id = :id');
            $STH->bindParam(':id', $id2edit);
            $STH->execute();
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo '<b>PDOException: </b>', $e->getMessage();
            die();
        }
    }
}

    try {
        $sql = "select id, name, price from goods";

        $STH = $DBH->query($sql);

        $STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        echo "<form method='post' >";
        echo "<table border='1'>";

        echo "<tr><th>Name</th><th>Price</th><th>Select</th></tr>";
        while ($row = $STH->fetch()) {
            echo "<tr><td><br>{$row["name"]} {$row["price"]} </td>";
            echo "<td>";
            echo "<input type='radio' value='{$row["id"]}' name='id2edit'>";
            echo "</td></tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
        echo "<br>";
        echo "<input type='submit' value='Delete selected product'         name='button'>";
        echo "</form>";

        $DBH = null;
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo '<b>PDOException: </b>', $e->getMessage();
        die();
    }
```

Comment: When i run your code, my tr with the goods and price and so on dont show up, i got an empty screen. When i remove the page from $action = isset($_GET['page']) and so on i can see it but cant delete anything. I dont understand why it cant show me the echos from it when i have page in the $action.

index.php?page=Delete (The page) is that it should work right?

Comment: I Have edited the Code. Please check. Also from your code it looked like you need to either delete or show the page. That is why I coded it like that.

Comment: Ok, i have now come further into the code, you can se my edit in the topic. Still i cant delete the value from the table.

Comment: Your code is wrong. Where is `$_GET['action']` in `index.php?page=Delete` ?  What's the difference between. `Delete` and `delete_record` ?

Comment: i changed my page = action instead. Then i dunno why it works, followed the tutorial, and now i can delete values from table.

Comment: Yes It should have worked with action only as you are using `$_GET['action']`